# How to update multiple nested/embedded document mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nested, document

I just want to know update all of the embedded documents. Here's my document:

```
{
"_id":1,
"chat":[
{ "sender":"bar",
"message":"Hi",
"status":"pending"
},
{ "sender":"bar",
"message":"How are you?",
"status":"pending"
}
}
{
"_id":2,
"chat":[
{ "sender":"foo",
"message":"Hello",
"status":"pending"
},
{ "sender":"foo",
"message":"Are you okay?",
"status":"pending"
},
{ "sender":"someone",
"message":"Where are you?",
"status":"pending"
}
}
```

I tried but it couldn't work simultaneously, it just works for change the first embedded document. Here's my code:

```
db.chat.update({"_id":"2", "chat.sender":"foo"},{$set{"chat.$.status":"sent"}},{multi:true})
```

I want document is updated to be like this and it should have changed in 1 process as simultaneously:

```
{
"_id":1,
"chat":[
{ "sender":"bar",
"message":"Hi",
"status":"pending"
},
{ "sender":"bar",
"message":"How are you?",
"status":"pending"
}
}
{
"_id":2,
"chat":[
{ "sender":"foo",
"message":"Hello",
"status":"sent"
},
{ "sender":"foo",
"message":"Are you okay?",
"status":"sent"
},
{ "sender":"someone",
"message":"Where are you?",
"status":"pending"
}
}
```

If you know how to solve this problem, please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
db.chat.find({ "_id":2 })
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.chat.forEach(function (ch) {
      if (ch.sender === "foo") {
        ch.status="sent";
      }
    });
    db.chat.save(doc);
  });
```

Comment: Omg it works sir, but how to implement in php ? db->chat->find(array("_id"=>"2")) and then ?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry but I can't help you about PHP. There must be a way to use that query in mongodb php library.

Comment: @ Hasan    find condition should be: { "_id" : 2}, make edit your ans.

Answer (score 0):

I think,You need this one. try like this,

```
db.chat.find({"_id":2,
    chat: {
        $exists: true
    }
}).forEach(function(myDoc) {
    var child = myDoc.chat;
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        var ob = child[i];
        if (ob.sender == "foo") {
            ob.status = "sent";
            child[i] = ob;
        }
    }
    db.chat.update({
        _id: myDoc._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            chat: child
        }
    });
    });
```